# Remove hash from React Router when using

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use the following code to change my React Router path:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'


var currentRouteName = this.props.location.pathname;
const path = currentRouteName + '/yes';
browserHistory.push(path);
```

The router looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/review/request/:id">
            <IndexRoute component={QuestionBox}/>
            <Route path="yes" component={PositiveBox}/>
            <Route path="no" component={NegativeBox}/>
            <Route path="thank-you" component={ThankYouComponent}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('parent-div'))
```

When I change the path with the above code I get a hashmark # in my URL, i.e. http://localhost:8080/review/request/5066549580791808/yes#

When I click back in the browser the hash will disappear and give me the path: http://localhost:8080/review/request/5066549580791808/yes

But the view won't update, if I hit back again, it will go back to the root path of:

http://localhost:8080/review/request/5066549580791808

And the view will change the IndexRoute again. What I think and what I want to have happen is to only have to hit the back button one time.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the answer and it's a tad bit annoying, in my click handler for my QuestionBox object it was like this:

```
click_like_button() {
        console.log("Like button clicked:", this); // React Component instance
        this.setState({should_hide: true});
        var currentRouteName = this.props.location.pathname;
        const path = currentRouteName + '/yes';
        browserHistory.push(path);
    }
```

Notice anything missing? I'm not passing in the actual event being generated by the click, so I changed it to this:

```
click_like_button(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Like button clicked:", this); // React Component instance
        this.setState({should_hide: true});
        var currentRouteName = this.props.location.pathname;
        const path = currentRouteName + '/yes';
        browserHistory.push(path);
    }
```

Now I have the event being passed in and then I do an event.preventDefault(); and ta-da it works! Why I had to do that I'm not sure, greater minds can no doubt tell you, but I think that gotcha is a little annoying and should either be fixed or warned on react-router.

Comment: Is the `click_like_button` method triggered by clicking on an anchor with an `href='#'` attribute? That might be why it added the hash to the URL. `event.preventDefault();` is a common way to prevent that from happening.

Comment: I agree with @FabianSchultz that you probably just have the `#` in an `href` causing that and without the `preventDefault()`, the default is to use the `#`.